# API request blocked by CORS policy, on ReactJS website deployed by Vercel

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, cors, vercel

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://apis.justwatch.com/content/titles/en_GB/popular?body={%22page_size%22:1,%22page%22:1,%22query%22:%22A+Bes%C3%BAg%C3%B3%22,%22content_types%22:[%22show%22]}' from origin 'https://leisure-os.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I get this error when attempting to make a request to apis.justwatch.com. However requests made api.tvmaze.com in my website, using the same method, works fine.

This is how I am making a request to the API, using Axios:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const search = async () => {
      console.log("locale: ", locale);
      //var locale = "en_GB";
      var type = "show";
      var n = 1;
      try {
        var data = await axios.get(
          "https://apis.justwatch.com/content/titles/" +
            locale +
            '/popular?body={"page_size":' +
            n +
            ',"page":1,"query":"' +
            q.split(" ").join("+") +
            '","content_types":["' +
            type +
            '"]}'
        );

        ...
```

The code to the website, with the live demo can be found here: github.com/moiz-i/leisureos

It works when I use a CORS unblocker chrome extension, but I want a permanent fix.

I have tried to use this code in my vercel.json, but it doesn't seem to make a difference:

```
{
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "src/index.js",
      "headers": [
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*" },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
          "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT"
        },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
          "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Got the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Thore if you call the api from the api folder(not in your main source file) then you won’t get a CORS error